# Check if class implements interface given the class name

Tags: java

Given

```
String className = "com.example.MyClass";
```

How would I be able to check if this class implements a specific interface?

I've tried

```
Class myClass = Class.forName(className);
if (myClass instanceof MyInterface) {}
```

and

```
if (myClass.isInstance(MyInterface.class)) {}
```

but neither work - obviously the Class object does not inherit MyInterface

What is the proper way to check if a class implements an interface only given the class name?

Comment: Try out the full accepted answer in the duplicate link, and if you still can't get it to work, drop a comment, and someone can reopen your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I disagree - the link provided shows how to load a class but not check its super type. Are you telling me i need to load a new instance of the class before I can check its super?

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming this.  AFAIK `instanceof` checks whether an _object_ is an instance of another class.  You never created an object, which is why I said to try the accepted answer exactly, and if it still doesn't work, then drop a note.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense now - I was hoping there was a way of doing this without having to load a new instance of the implementation.

Thanks for clarifying

Comment: I un-duped your answer, I was going to answer, but felt I would just be copying someone else's answer and changing maybe 1-2 lines.  But hopefully your problem is solved now.

Comment: Lol, now that I think about it - you should probably leave it duped as that answer does contain the key. I don't think this is possible w/o loading the implementation class; otherwise you're just left with a Class object

Maybe I could achieve something similar through generics?
Class<? extends MyInterface> myClass = Class.forName(myClass); ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-):

```
if (MyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(myClass)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: heh - just looked at what i was doing and realized i was passing in the wrong class ( face palm )